# Nativescript-vue: In Android users exception was stop work

Tags: android, nativescript-vue

There is an error in my Android program. If you do the following, the program starts working incorrectly:

1. Launch the program
2. Open the Android system settings
3. Change the font size in them
4. Go back to my program

After that, events that I create stop working in the program. If the event is a typical one (for example, @tap for the < Label > control), it continues to work. If the event is called manually by me in this way:

```js
    this.$emit ("update:text", this.textFieldValue);
```

then it doesn't work.

What I did wrong?

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. I would suggest grammarly.com for better explaining your self. If more people will understand your question, more solutions will follow. {N} Playground or a repo link will also help.

Comment: Thank you:) OK. I rewrite the content of my problem. I hope now it's more understood.